# OpenCV border mode issue with blur filter

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been stuck on this for a few days now, maybe someone will be able to help me here.

I'm using OpenCV C++ API to perform some basic image processing. I have a step where I want to blur my image and specify `BORDER_WRAP`as my border type :

```
cv::blur(img, img, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Point(-1, -1), cv::BORDER_WRAP);
```

But when executing my code, I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (columnBorderType != BORDER_WRAP)

However, everything works fine when I use other border types, (`BORDER_REFLECT` for example), but I need `BORDER_WRAP`

Things seem to work if I use `copyMakeBorder(img, img, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv::BORDER_WRAP)` first on my image, blur this new image and then crop it back to the size of the original one, but still I can't figure out why my first try doesn't work.

Anyone knows how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. `BORDER_WRAP` is not accepted by all functions - it's valid just for a few of them and, as the assertion failure confirms, `cv::blur` is not one of them..

But as you've already found out yourself, you can first use `cv::copyMakeBorder`, blur this new image and crop it back to the size of the original.

Comment: so if a function/filter allows border modes directly, they don't call copyMakeBorder internally but use the border mode implicitly (and therefore more efficiently)?

Comment: @Micka I reckon that the built-in opencv filters will simply emit an assertion failure Error (as in this case) for those particular border modes that are not supported. Then it's up to you (or any third-party library implementor) to decide if they want to implicitly call cv::copyMakeBorder or some other function as a work around.

Comment: no I meant if some border type IS supported by the filter, will the filter apply the border implicitly, without copying the image and adding the border explicitly?

Comment: @Micka I don't know about this. I suggest you look at the source code directly. Note however that this is an implementation detail, and even if in currently borders are applied in a particular way there is no guarantee that they also be in the future. Implementors may always change those algorithms to achieve better performance, to fix some bug or for some other reason.

Comment: Thanks Marinos, I'll stick to copyMakeBorder + crop then

Comment: Yet another example of pathetic opencv documentation.